# Get a list of users interrogating a public api using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have to create exercise project in asp core, i have sample api to query for returning list of all users. I have auth token and making test from postman works fine.

I have write a controller that recall a service that make a get request.
I have also a service recalled by controller tath do a get request.

a this point i cant able to convert my response in a list of user (really i have to use user dto object here), and i dont know i i can use ef to have all data in the context:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllAsync(string token, string 
   baseUrl)
   {
     using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())

    //Setting up the response...         
    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl + 
    "users?access-token=" + token))
    using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
    {

        var data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync<List<UserDto>>();
        if (data != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res.StatusCode);

        }
    }
    // this row is wrong, i have to use ef and put in context all list here
    return _context.Users;

}
```

I have loaded sample solution that reproduce the issue on google drive here: drive.google.com/open?id=1-cZU01sjZ5aRf4OGGOxIZpYiSbQnXr1p

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after running your sample code, I managed to get it to work by creating a proper JSON object based on the JSON response (using json2csharp.com)

Here is the working GetAllAsync() method

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>> GetAllAsync(string token, string baseUrl)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())

        //Setting up the response...         
        using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl +
        "users?access-token=" + token))
        using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
        {
            string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

            var users = new List<UserDto>();

            // Now map the result to UserDto
            foreach (var r in rootObject.result)
            {
                users.Add(
                    new UserDto
                    {
                        id = int.Parse(r.id),
                        first_name = r.first_name,
                        last_name = r.last_name,
                        username = r.id, // We don't receive a username back?
                        gender = r.gender,
                        dob = r.dob,
                        email = r.email,
                        phone = r.phone,
                        website = r.website,
                        address = r.address,
                        status = r.status,
                        links = new List<string> // Looks like the response includes 3 links to self, edit and avatar
                        {
                            r._links.self.href,
                            r._links.edit.href,
                            r._links.avatar.href
                        }
                    });
            }

            return users;
        }
    }
```

And here are the JSON DTOs:

```
public class RateLimit
{
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int remaining { get; set; }
    public int reset { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
    public int pageCount { get; set; }
    public int currentPage { get; set; }
    public int perPage { get; set; }
    public RateLimit rateLimit { get; set; }
}

public class Self
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Edit
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Avatar
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    public Self self { get; set; }
    public Edit edit { get; set; }
    public Avatar avatar { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Links _links { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta _meta { get; set; }
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

This is tested and working! Enjoy.

Comment: Doesnt work , i have a JSON.NET error “Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {”name“:”value“})”. I have loaded sample solution that reproduce the issue on google drive here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-cZU01sjZ5aRf4OGGOxIZpYiSbQnXr1p

Comment: Please see my posted answer, I was able to get your project to work by implementing the JSON object structure based on the actual JSON response. Then you can parse the JSON result and map the users into your List<UserDto> list. I noticed there is no username field, so you will need to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, no username is not required i have deleted it from entities

Answer (score 0):

Try: (this solution requires Json.NET)

```
string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
UserDto value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDto>(json);
```

Be carefull not to have extra '\', '"' or any other chars in the returned json.

Comment: Doesnt work , i have the result and content into it but cannot convert in a list of dto objects, i have ddited my question because i have need to convert into a list of dto, (the json return me all users)